# Convert image to encrypted PDF in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Bullzip to encrypt and send my reports from Access.

I'd like to have a sub, where I could load any external picture, (they'd mostly be A4 format, jpeg) and save it as pdf (and later encrypt it and send, but I have that part covered.)

Is it possible from Access?

I could throw a picture into a report and send that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), and use it's [command-line tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) to convert jpg images to PDF files.

You can use `Shell` in VBA to execute the commands.

Example:

`Shell "Magick Convert C:\Image.JPG C:\Image.PDF"`

Comment: tx, I'll try this out